# Add 'Currency' filter in custom filer - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, filter

i want to add builtin filter - currency to my custom filter.  Trying to do in angular js

```
 (function(angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('testApp')
        .filter('amount', function() {
            return function(amount) {
                if (!amount) {
                    return 'Invalid Amount';
                } else {
                    //Here i want to add CURRENCY filter "| currency"
                    return amount;
                }
            }
        })
})();
```

Comment: return "$"+ amount;  Is it not working?

Comment: i want to format the currency like $5,493,274.86

Answer (score 0):

You can use number filter. Try it please

```
.filter('amount', function($filter) {
            return function(amount) {
                if (!amount) {
                    return 'Invalid Amount';
                } else {
                    //Here i want to add CURRENCY filter "| currency"
                    var newAmount = $filter('number')(amount, 2);
                    return "$"+ newAmount;
                }
            }
  })
```

or this like

```
return $filter('currency')(amount, "$", 2);
```

Comment: yeah, it's working perfectly. thank you.. return $filter('currency')(amount, "$", 2);